# Linq count of subtable slow compared to SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, linq, entity-framework, count

I'm trying to select a table and count all of its assigned rows in an subtable, but there seems to be an performance issue?

When I run this Linq query against our Oracle DB it just never stops:

```
From a In TABLE1
Select New  With {
.ID = a.ID,
.COUNT = (From c In TABLE2 Where c.ID2 = a.ID).Count
}
```

When I look at the SQL in LINQPad it translates like the following using COALESCE and CASE:

```
SELECT t0.ID, (
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE2 t1
WHERE COALESCE(CASE WHEN ((t1.ID2 = t0.ID)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 0) <> 0
) c0
FROM TABLE1 t0
```

When I run my own query against the DB it only takes about 5 sec.

```
SELECT t0.ID, (
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE2 t1
WHERE t1.ID2 = t0.ID
)
FROM TABLE1 t0
```

Is there a way to ged rid of COALESCE and CASE in the poor translation or gain some performance elsewhere?

Comment: do you try to use GROUP JOIN?

Comment: Any chance you could give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you try to use GROUP JOIN?

```
From a In TABLE1
Join c In TABLE2 on c.ID2 Equals a.ID into g
Select New  With {
.ID = a.ID,
.COUNT = g.Count
}
```

**Here is the SQL generated:**

```
SELECT [t0].[ID] AS [ID], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [TABLE2] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t0].[ID] = ([t1].[ID2])
    ) AS [Count]
FROM [TABLE1] AS [t0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much it is now the same query and it should take the same time but if I execute it in LINQPad it takes 30 sec and only 5 via SQLPlus or Toad?